# what should by handler be called when deploying a simple api to AWS LAMBDA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

learning lambdas and trying to deploy the stock web api weatherforecast to aws lambda.

i've put my handler as:

```
SimpleApi::Controllers.WeatherForecastController::Get
```

my folder structure is the standard web api weatherforcast boilerplate
[image: standardsetup]

but when i publish and check the lambda function url i get:

Internal Server Error

and when i invoke from visual studio i get this error:

```
  "errorType": "LambdaValidationException",
  "errorMessage": "Unable to load type 'Controllers.WeatherForecastController' from assembly 'SimpleApi'.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Init(Action`1 customerLoggingAction) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 112",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeInitializer.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeInitializer.cs:line 46",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 155"
  ]
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

i've changed the handler to 'SimpleApi' but i get this error

```
{
  "errorType": "NullReferenceException",
  "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass26_0`2.<<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0>d.MoveNext()",
    "--- End of stack trace from previous location ---",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
  ]
}
```

and a 404 when hitting my function URL

Comment: Change the handler name to assembly name which is SimpleApi in your case.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work, i've updated the question with that change

Comment: See [Handler signatures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html#csharp-handler-signatures). I note that your `Get `method takes no parameters. Lambda functions have parameters. I don't know if this is your problem but worth verifying.